# FontAwesome -> Icons broken

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, debugging, templates

[image]

Having trouble with a template that I'm using. The icons is not working. I guess that the web configuration does not accept woff and ttf as an extension.

BTW im using pyrocms 3.0 laravel

Comment: Check the URLs for the fonts, because the browser is unable to locate the resource. Also, why aren't you using the bootstrap CDN? https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Answer (score 0):

- Observe URL if you are pointing well
- Configuration laravel may be blocking the exit of internet search fonts
- Clear browser cache